# Why does my ArrayList doesn't store my EditText entries but just display them

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, android-edittext

I have a `FragmentStatePager` with two `EditText` and a custom `ListView`. 
The User can make two inputs and click on a `Button` and they will be added to the `ListView` but they won't be stored in the `ListView`.The `ListView` contains a `ArrayList`.

I want that the inputs of the `EditText` will be stored in that `ArrayList`.

Can somebody write how to do it ?

---

My *onCreateView*

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.swipeview, container, false);
        txtTitel = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeviewtitle);


        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitel.setText(titel[position]);


        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeViewimage);
        // Capture position and set to the ImageView

        String title = titel[position];
        Integer imageRes = TITLE_IMAGES.get(title);
        if (imageRes == null) { // not found in map
            image.setImageResource(0);
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(imageRes);
        }


        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewswipeview);
        final EditText wdhedittext = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextswipeView);
        final EditText kgedittext = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final Button btnswipeview = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonswipeview);





        adapter2 = new CustomListViewAdapter2(getActivity(),
                R.layout.swipeviewrowitem, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter2);



        btnswipeview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View View) {

                if (wdhedittext.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Bitte Wiederholungszahl angeben",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (kgedittext.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    final rowitem2 item = new rowitem2(wdhedittext.getText().toString() + "wdh", kgedittext.getText().toString());

                    adapter2.add(item);
                    rowItems.add(item);

                } else {
                    final rowitem2 item = new rowitem2(wdhedittext.getText().toString() + "wdh", kgedittext.getText().toString() + "kg");
                    adapter2.add(item);
                    rowItems.add(item);

                /*String name = wdhedittext.getText().toString();
                int rowId = workoutDBAO2.addWorkout2(name);
                HashMap rowValsSets = new HashMap();
                rowValsSets.put("sets", name);
                rowValsSets.put("id", rowId);
                adapter3.add(rowValsSets);*/
                }


            }
        });


        rowItems = new ArrayList<rowitem2>();


        return rootView;
    }
```

*CustomListViewAdapter2* and *rowitem2* classes

```
class CustomListViewAdapter2 extends ArrayAdapter<rowitem2> {


        private final ArrayList<rowitem2> items;
        Context context;

        public CustomListViewAdapter2(Context context, int resourceId,
                                      ArrayList<rowitem2> items) {
            super(context, resourceId, items);
            this.context = context;
            this.items=items;
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            rowitem2 rowItem = items.get(position);

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipeviewrowitem, null);
                TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mainText2);
                TextView txtDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
            txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());


            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
class rowitem2 {

        private String edittexttitle;
        private String edittexttitle2;

        public rowitem2(String title, String desc) {
            this.edittexttitle = title;
            this.edittexttitle2 = desc;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return edittexttitle;
        }

        public String getDesc() {
            return edittexttitle2;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.edittexttitle = title;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return edittexttitle + "\n" + edittexttitle2;
        }


    }
```

Comment: You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when the list changes

Comment: that doesn't change anything. The values still disappear .

Comment: Just a note, the Java convention is to write `class` names with a beginning capital letter, e.g. `private class MyClass{}`

Answer (score 0):

dapter2.notifyDataSetChanged() after adding the item will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not persist any data in the `ArrayList`. If you want to store them permanently, you should use a `SQLite database` or `SharedPreferences`.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a good example on how to solve your problem using a SQLite database. This is useful if you plan to store and manage a lot of data.

If you do not plan on storing a lot of data, using `SharedPreferences` would be a neat option. For example:

```
//Store a String in SharedPreferences 
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("your_key", your_string_variable);
```

And whenever you want to retrieve it (for instance, `onResume` or `onCreate`)

```
 // Restore preferences
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 String your_string_variable = settings.getString("your_key", "default_value");
```

More information regarding SharedPreferences can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Later I want that there is a `Spinner` which contains dates when the user added inputs in the `ListView`(I think there will not be more than 6 inputs for each day). So every day when he add a input there should be a clear `ListView` but the old one should be stored and the user should see them when he select one date of the `Spinner`. So what do you think is better? `SQLite database` or `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: In that case, I would recommend looking into the `SQLite database` example. There is no other simple way of storing data rather than in a database. However, explaining the whole database concept as an answer to your question would be too broad. I suggest that you start implementing your database, and if you have upcoming questions, post them more specifically described as new questions. @nick04

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please tick it as accepted answer :-) @nick04